# SfmcSDK Error: Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, android, mobilepush-android, react-native

I've been testing push notifications on Android and got the following log on crashlytics and logcat. Important to note that I've received the notification successfully and had no problems opening the app when tapping the notification, just wanted to follow-up on possible impacts could happen because of this behavior.

Error occurred on Android 13, I'm not able to test more versions at the moment. More info bellow:

React Native app dependencies:

```
"react-native": "0.72.6",
"react-native-marketingcloudsdk": "^8.1.0"
```

Android configuration on `MainApplication.java`:

```
SFMCSdk.configure((Context) this, SFMCSdkModuleConfig.build(builder -> {
      builder.setPushModuleConfig(MarketingCloudConfig.builder()
              .setApplicationId(BuildConfig.mc_application_id)
              .setAccessToken(BuildConfig.mc_access_token)
              .setSenderId(BuildConfig.fcm_sender_id)
              .setMarketingCloudServerUrl(BuildConfig.mc_app_server_url)
              .setDelayRegistrationUntilContactKeyIsSet(true)
              .setNotificationCustomizationOptions(
                NotificationCustomizationOptions.create(
                  R.drawable.ic_notification
                )
              )
              .setAnalyticsEnabled(true)
              .build(this));

      return null;
    }), initializationStatus -> {
        Log.e("STATUSS", String.valueOf(initializationStatus.getStatus()));
      if (initializationStatus.getStatus() == 1) {
          Log.e("STATUSS", "STATUS SUCCESS");
      } else {
        Log.e("STATUSS", "Error");
        Log.e("STATUSS", String.valueOf(initializationStatus.getStatus()));
      }
      return null;
    });
```

Android log:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.salesforce.marketingcloud.notifications.NotificationOpenActivity$a@6199b6a
       at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1769)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1899)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:829)
       at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.notifications.NotificationOpenActivity$a.onReceive(:2)
       at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:59)
       at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:11)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A release to address this issue is scheduled to be released no later than 01/23/2024.

Comment: Hello, do we have any updates on this? Has the update been published? We're receiving a lot of reports on Firebase related to this issue, our last published version was released on Feb 8th

Comment: This issue was resolved in version 8.1.4 of the SDK. 8.1.5 is currently available and should be the version you adopt if you're upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

Please update to at least version 8.1.4 of the Android SDK to resolve this issue.

Comment: I just checked and our latest version is already using 8.1.4 and we're still receiving the reports on Firebase. We'll update to 8.1.5 soon and keep monitoring the reports, thank you for the follow up!

Comment: Github had an outage that prevented `gh-pages` from being updated correctly. If you have reports of this on 8.1.4 I suspect you have a bad artifact for 8.1.4 and you should clear any locally cached artifacts before building. That said, 8.1.5 is the better choice anyway.